# Passing a Keras Generator to __call__ method of My Model

Tags: python, keras, generator, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have written my own keras Model, and I'm trying to pass a Keras Generator as input to model.fit.
The problem is that I don't know how to process the generator, when I'm in the **call** method of MyModel. How do I access the x and y from the generator in order to pass them as inputs to my Encoder and Decoder Network, and also keep the generator working its magic, loading the batches each epoch ?

Ok so this MyModel class which inherits tf.keras.Model

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.enc = Encoder()
    self.dec1 = Decoder1()
    self.dec2 = Decoder2()

def __call__(self, data_generator, **kwargs):

    ################################################ 
    ? how do I acces x and y in order to pass them to the encoder and decoder ? 
    and also keep the generator proprieties
    ###############################################
    x_train, y_train = data_generator # ?????????
    #####################################

    dec_inputs = tf.concat((tf.zeros_like(y_train[:, :1, :]), y_train[:, :-1, :]), 1)  
                                                                                      
    dec_inputs = dec_inputs[:, :, -hp.n_mels:] 

    print("########ENC INPUTS #####")
    #print(tf.shape(x_train))
    print("######################")

    print("#########DEC INPUTS #####")
    #print(tf.shape(dec_inputs))
    print("######################")

    memory = self.enc(x_train)
    y_hat = self.dec1(dec_inputs, memory)
    #z_hat = self.dec2(y_hat)
    return y_hat
```

And this is my generator function

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

def __init__(self, list_IDs, ID_dictionary, labels, batch_size=8, dim1=(32, 32, 32), dim2=(32, 32, 32),
             n_channels=None, n_classes=None, shuffle=True):
    'Initialization'

    self.dim1 = dim1  # dimensiune X
    self.dim2 = dim2  # dimensiune Y
    self.batch_size = batch_size

    self.ID_dictionary = ID_dictionary
    self.labels = labels
    self.list_IDs = list_IDs

    self.n_channels = n_channels
    self.n_classes = n_classes

    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.on_epoch_end()

def __len__(self):
    'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
    return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

# 3
def __getitem__(self, index):
    'Generate one batch of data'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    indexes = self.indexes[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size] 

    # Find list of IDs
    list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]         

    # Generate data
    x, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)  

    return x, y

# 1
def on_epoch_end(self):
    'Updates indexes after each epoch'
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))  
    if self.shuffle == True:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

# 2
def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
    # Initialization            
    x = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.dim1)) 
    y = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim2), dtype=float)

    # Generate data
    for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):  
        # Store sample
        x[i, ] = self.ID_dictionary[ID]       
        # Store class
        y[i] = self.labels[ID]                  
    return x, y
```

And this is how I call MyModel in main

```
 listID, dict1, dict2, text_shape, mel_shape = get_batch()
 # dict1 has the inputs ( text ) and dict2 has the labels ( the mels )
 
 training_generator = DataGenerator(listID, dict1, dict2, dim1=text_shape, dim2=mel_shape)

 model = MyModel()


 model.compile(
      optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
      metrics=["accuracy"],

      )

  #model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, use_multiprocessing=True, workers=6)
  model.fit(training_generator, epochs=2)
```

Comment: why do you want to pass the generator to the call method of model class?

Comment: Because I know that the __call__ method is called when i do model.fit. And in model.fit I need to pass my training_generator which contains the input

Comment: If I don't pass a generator as an argument to the __call__ and instead I put let's say 
__call__(self, x_train, y_train) ...

and then in the main function I simply do

model.fit(train_generator, epochs=2)

then an error will pop up telling me that I need to also pass y_train. But the x_train and y_train are contained in the training_generator

Comment: yes you are right that call method is called in model.fit, the thing is that the call method expects one input to it i.e x_input, so when keras internally pass parameter python throws error that y_train is not given which is expected behaviour, so the call method should have only one input x_input, rest will be handled automatically inside the fit function

Comment: your generator is used in fit function to fetch x_input, y_input, and subsequently your x_input is passed to the call method of the model class

Comment: Ok I understand

Comment: But I need x_train and also y_train. I need y_train to pass it to the decoder input. Should i make a separate generator for y ? And then i will have generator_x and generator_y...and then i could pass both generators to the call function ?. Thank you for all your answers so far :D

Comment: you can but you will then have to create your own train function to pass arbitrary number of parameters to your call function, otherwise if you are using fit function it will pass x_input which it will get from your data generator.

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer i'll write it down below

Comment: Ok. So you are saying that I need to create my own training function. My own " fit ".  Isn't there an easier way ?:)). If not can you please show me how to do it ? :D. Thank you again !

Comment: easier way would be to not pass data generator in the call function, instead use x_input and pass it to the encoder or decoder in the call function of your model, showing how to train model with custom training loop would be out of the scope of this question. I would refer : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models and https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention

Comment: i'll post my answer below for the same

Comment: Well. I really need to pass the generator as the input, otherwise i can't load all my input dataset in one variable x_train because it will tell me i'm out of memory.

Comment: So I have to write my own fit function

Comment: If that is the case dont worry when you pass generator to the fit method it will be used to fetch one element from your data and pass it to the call function

Comment: I am sorry but you are not getting what im trying to say if you are only passing generator to get chunks of data you dont need that, you are already passing it your fit function, your call function will receive what your generator is yielding

Comment: If you still want to pass generator somehow then yes you will have to create you own training step function

Comment: No ! I really understood what you said.

Comment: My only problem remains. How can I also access the y_train ? Because only passing one variable to the call function ( the generator in our case ) it will give me chunks of data for x_train. But how can i also pass the input for the decoder...as it is different from x_train

Comment: i have updated my answer please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call method` is called in `model.fit`, which expects one input to it i.e `x_input`, so you cannot expect generator as the input of the call method when using model.fit method. Please read tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models and tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention for greater understanding how things are working.

Edit 1: how can you pass two variables in call method

```py
# pass list [x,y] to your call function instead of only x, we will club x and y into one variable
def __call__(self, inputs):
    x = inputs[0]
    y = inputs[1]
    # now you can use x and y coming from your generator without changing much


# update your generator to return [x,y] and y
def generator
    yield [x, y], y

# simply call model.fit like you were doing before
model.fit(generator)
```

Comment: YOU'RE THE MAN ! Now I really understood. Thank you for your patience. God Bless you :D

Comment: Great. Thank you happy coding to you xD

Comment: please accept the answer if you feel your query is resolved @SerjIonescu

Comment: Done ! I almost forgot. Thank you again :D